# Speech Synthesis API supports a language on the phone but not on desktop

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, speech, speech-synthesis

I am about to use Speech Synthesis API in an ongoing project, and before moving on I was about to collect as much data/demo on web as possible.
Hereby an example, but the phenomenon is always the same, regardless the demos I tried: http://labs.qnimate.com/speech-synthesis-api/

So, the point is, that on my mobile, I can choose 'hu-HU' but, as it seems to be it is not a possibility on PC (Chrome as well).

Chrome Versions:

- Mobile: 50.0.2261.89
- Desktop : 50.0.2661.94

Any idea, what causes the difference?

Comment: The voices present on Android aren't necessarily available in Google Chrome. You can call `speechSynthesis.getVoices()` on Chrome's JS console to see the voices it returns. It returns one or two dozen of the most used voices. Any voices not present in the list cannot be used.